# MySQL: Join Condition ON Multiple Column Values

Tags: mysql, join

Here's the query:

```
    SELECT CONCAT(imp_us_storefront.model,'/',imp_us_storefront.chassis) AS rec_desc, 1 AS flag,asc_model.model_id AS model,asc_chassis.chassis_id AS chassis
    FROM imp_us_storefront 
      JOIN asc_model ON (asc_model.rec_desc = imp_us_storefront.model)
      JOIN asc_chassis ON (asc_chassis.rec_desc = imp_us_storefront.chassis)
      JOIN attr_notebook ON (asc_model.model_id != attr_notebook.model_id AND asc_chassis.chassis_id != attr_notebook.chassis_id)
    WHERE imp_us_storefront.mri_category = '11946'
    GROUP BY rec_desc ASC;
```

For this particular category '11946' all the chassis_id's have the same value so the result set is empty.  If I eliminate the constraint

```
    asc_chassis_chassis_id != attr_notebook.chassis_id
```

Then I get the result I need, but this does not work with other categories.  So my question is how do I transfrom this line

```
    JOIN attr_notebook ON (asc_model.model_id != attr_notebook.model_id AND asc_chassis.chassis_id != attr_notebook.chassis_id)
```

to eliminate only a specific combination of model_id and chassis_id so that if I have the following values

model_id     chassis_id

2                 6

3                 6

I can eliminate 2,6 but not 3,6

OR

model_id     chassis_id

4                 2

4                 3

I can eliminate 4,2 but not 4,3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you determine which combinations you wish to keep and which you wish to eliminate?